# JsonDeserialize not work for LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to send POST request from my client to my backend, and in the POJO I have two fields LocalDate and LocalDateTime as follows:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime createdTimestamp;

@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private LocalDate expiredDate;
```

The client will send request with body like:

```json
{
    "expiredDate" : "01.01.2020",
    "createdTimestamp" : "01.02.2020 - 10:10:10"  
}
```

In the backend, however, I got an exception:

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

And if I leave the `createdTimestamp` out of request's body then it worked. It seems that only the annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)` worked, while the `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)` did not work.

Does anyone have an idea why this happened?

Comment: You have a lowercase `h` for hours in your pattern, but there's no `a` specifying if those hours are `AM` or `PM`. That might be a problem, but I am not sure. Make the hours be uppercase `H` to describe hours in 24h-format and try again. Could work...

Comment: yes as said @deHaar your POJO properties does not match the one of your client :
`createdTimestamp != createTimestamp` or is that a typo ?

Comment: Sorry the createdTimestamp is my typo, the solution from deHaar worked for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good... I made it an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the symbol for hours in 12h format (`hh`) in your pattern, but the pattern is incomplete because it is missing an indicator for `AM`/`PM`, which would be an `a`. Leaving that indicator makes the time expression ambiguous, it could be `10 AM` or `10 PM` (`22` in 24h-format).

You could just switch the format to 24h format (`HH`), which would make the time unambiguous.

Like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime createdTimestamp;
```